# Checking a radio with no id and class through Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to programmatticaly check this radio buton using javascript:

```
<input type="radio" name="LINK_TYPE" value="normal">
```

But in that page there are other elements with the same name, but different values. How can I check just the one with the value="normal"?

I've tried something like this:

```
document.querySelector('input[name=LINK_TYPE]:checked').normal;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You have the tag "id" in HTML for a reason, use it. ID should be unique for each element present in the DOM

Comment: @Floaterz The OP specifically mentioned there's no `id`. In the title.

Comment: It's not my website, and the website has not id elements. Still thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Chris G, so what's keeping him from adding one? this is a simple case of adding an ID and then do the manipulation in javascript.

Comment: @Floaterz All kinds of external reasons could be keeping the OP from adding one. If they specifically ask how to select an element that has no id, why "help" by questioning that basic premise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like you used the `name` value selector, use the `value` selector.

```
document.querySelector('input[name="LINK_TYPE"][value="normal"]').checked = true;
```

Note that there should be no space between the two attribute-value selectors and `input`.